# How do I change vims character set of stdin?

Tags: vim, character-encoding, stdin

```
echo "UTF-16le text"|vim -
:set encoding=utf-16le
:set fileencoding=utf-16le
:e! ++enc=utf-16le
```

has absolutely no effect on the mojibake that is displayed on the screen.  Though the last one (`:e! ++enc=utf-16le`) results in an error `E32: No file name`.

If I edit `~/.vimrc` to `set fileencodings=utf-16le,[...]` then it works, but I shouldn't have to edit my configuration file every time I use vim, is there a better way?  Preferably a way in which a key code will just cycle between my `:set fileencodings`, that way I can choose quickly if needed.

Comment: The few UTF-16LE [samples](https://bitbucket.org/EricFromCanada/ericfromcanada.bitbucket.org/raw/55865a3ee2bfdddf6c6c3253ab3db62653c5e59c/applescript/close%20Safari%20Web%20Inspector.applescript) I could find on the web opened correctly (readable and `fileencoding` automatically set to `utf-16le`) in Vim without having to set any option.

Comment: I think the best way it is to pipe the file to `iconv`. Main vim usage is not to get file from file (as stdin), but to use console (so keys), which has a own API/"encoding".

Answer (score 0):

The command-line equivalent to `~/.vimrc` is passing commands via `--cmd`. You can also employ the `:help :set^=` command to prepend a value to an option:

```
echo "UTF-16le text"|vim --cmd 'set fencs^=utf-16le' -
```

---

> I shouldn't have to edit my configuration file every time I use vim

First, I would test whether permanently keeping `utf-16le` in `'fileencodings'` has any negative consequences for any files you regularly edit; maybe you can safely keep it in by default.

Second, there are plugins like [AutoFenc](https://github.com/s3rvac/AutoFenc), which extends the built-in detection, and [fencview](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1708), which let's you choose the encoding from a menu.

#### Alternative

The problem with UTF-16 encodings is well known, and the *byte order mark* is one solution to make it easy to detect those. With such a BOM, Vim will correctly detect the encoding out-of-the-box. If your input is missing the BOM, you can manually prepend it:

```
{ printf '\xFF\xFE'; echo "UTF-16le text"; } | vim -
```